# Does "尚" mean studying or learning?

Tags: characters, vocabulary

在中国大陆, 有一些非学历教育机构的名称都用了"尚"字.
例如: **尚**学堂, **尚**硅谷 (前两者都是Java编程培训机构); **尚**德 (成人学历提升)

"尚"字在汉语里有类似教育, 学习之类的意思吗? 为什么这些教育机构会想到这种字起名呢?

当然, 在[百度汉语](https://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=%E5%B0%9A&query=%E5%B0%9A&srcid=28532&from=kg1)中有:

> 加上, **往…上补充东西**
>   尚之以琼华乎而. --*诗·齐风·著*
>
> 又如: 尚絅 (穿锦衣时加上罩袍, 以使华美不显耀于外)

这些培训机构起名是根据这条释义以"提升"为考量的吗? 还是说"尚"字也有学习的含义?

Comment: 仅凭您的提问来看，似乎汉语已经掌握得不错了，我有些好奇怎么还会有这样的问题呢QwQ

Comment: @TooskyHierot 我是母语者，但我语文没学好

Comment: 可。这个问题的回答很简单：广告，商标的用词，常常会故意更改既成词语中的字，以达到出彩、吸睛的目的。有的时候仅仅只是美好意义的词的堆砌，并不确定要解释作什么，是任由发挥的事情。“尚”作为“上”的常见代替，我记得决不只是在教育培训机构出现，所以并不见得其非要有什么关系。

Comment: @TooskyHierot The best answer over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

尚 means: esteem; value; uphold

尚 can be short for 崇尚  (to advocate; uphold)

"尚学" can be interpreted as "崇尚学問" (advocating knowledge)

"尚德" can be interpreted as "崇尚美德" (advocating virtue)

"尚武" can be interpreted as "崇尚武學" (advocating martial arts)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment by Toosky.

A **pun** is intended here. 尚学堂，尚硅谷 is pronounced the same as 上学堂，上硅谷, which sounds welcoming.  On the other hand , 尚 itself has other decent meanings as in 高尚，时尚，etc.